# how to implement pdf.js to view pdf files in the pdf viewer?

Tags: pdf, pdf.js

i want to open pdf files that are linked to in a document in a new page in the pdf.js viewer.

i have downloaded the zip file from github:

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

and gone to both of the index.html files in the examples folder.

i get blank pages when opening either of these files.

can anyone please tell me how to implement pdf.js so that i can open pdf documents in a new page in the pdf viewer?

thank you.

Comment: Which browser do you use? The viewer does not work correctly in IE

Comment: hello, thank you for your reply, i use chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using '?file=url' in query-string with viewer.html.
For example: www.example.com/pdf-js/web/viewer.html?File="URL"

Source: [pdf-js on github](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2496#issuecomment-11597900)

And yes, you will most definitely have cross-domain issues if not using any web-server, as mentioned by @Silent.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess that you tried to directly open the examples via chrome. Your url probably starts off with file:///. This is causing a cross origin request error to occur on your browser. To properly view the examples, you need a LAMP stack.