# How to open a pdf file in viewer.html of pdf.js?

Tags: cordova, pdf, pdf.js

I stock pdf files in a server and I'd like to open them in a cordova application on which I'm working.
For that purpose I have downloaded the files from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/ and I just add a link  to

/web/viewer.html?file=http://www.myservername.com/pdf/mypdf.pdf

as recommended in [how to implement pdf.js to view pdf files in the pdf viewer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917749/how-to-implement-pdf-js-to-view-pdf-files-in-the-pdf-viewer)

Unfortunately it doesn't work (it opens an empty pdf container), so I'm wondering if someone could help me out on that issue. Thank you